# TypeError: key must be a string, a buffer or an object at typeError with GCP file exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, nodemon

I'm trying to simply test for an existence of a file on our Google Cloud Platform (GCP) storage. I'm using GCP buckets on express js servers. Below is essentially a very simple exampled copied off of https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#exists

EDIT: This is how I authenticate the GCP key:

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: 'my-cloud',
    keyFilename: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
});
const bucketName = 'my-ci';
```

(With small changes, I realise you are supposed to return `data[0]`)

```js
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
const file = bucket.file(path);
const exists = await file.exists().then(data => {
    return data
})
```

But when I try run this, I get the error:

```
[nodemon] starting `node --inspect server/server.js`
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/9a677766-4a93-4499-b57c-55f5f05096d7
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Server listening on port 4000!
/opt/node_modules/jwa/index.js:115
return new TypeError(errMsg);
^

TypeError: key must be a string, a buffer or an object
at typeError (/opt/node_modules/jwa/index.js:115:10)
at checkIsPrivateKey (/opt/node_modules/jwa/index.js:61:9)
at Object.sign (/opt/node_modules/jwa/index.js:147:5)
at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (/opt/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:32:24)
at JWTAccess.getRequestHeaders (/opt/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtaccess.js:87:31)
at JWT.getRequestMetadataAsync (/opt/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:76:51)
at JWT.getRequestHeaders (/opt/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:238:37)
at GoogleAuth.authorizeRequest (/opt/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:593:38)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Since the error message did not give a useful traceback, I did some digging on my own. Through putting `console.log` statements everywhere, I narrowed it down to the line

```js
const exists = await file.exists().then(data => {
    return data
})
```

and tried various approaches from removing the `.then(...)` clause, to removing the `await` (which, does work until the promise is resolved). None of these seemed to have worked.

What may be potential causes of this?

Comment: according to stack trace it fails during login (GoogleAuth, google-auth-library) and does not seem to reach your code

Comment: According to [the docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html#Storage-examples) you need to create `new Storage()` and pass a keyfile to it

Comment: You have a credential problem. Where is this code running? If locally, did you set up the Google Cloud CLI and authenticate? If running in Google Cloud on a compute service, such as Compute Engine, did you set up the instance to have storage access? More details about how you are authorizing your application to access storage are needed.

Comment: @Vitalii @Jon Hanley I do in the code. I've edited the post that includes where I define it with the right GCP key via the environment variable. But why does the code fail at `const exists = await file.exists( ...` line? Surely it should fail when I try `const file = bucket.file(path);`?

Answer (score 4):

Eventually figured it out - it was due to the GCP key being an older version of the key. If you get an error like above, try to check that your key is correct.

Comment: thx, I did not think about it, this saved me a lot of pain

Comment: I just generated the key so I am not sure if that is my issue.